# Where is the right and the best place to save shared data like {user displayed name, user id} in the runtime ,using angular 13?

Tags: angular, rxjs

In **angular 13**, Where is the right and the best place to save shared data like {user displayed name, user id}  in **the runtime**. So we can use them in different modules or component?

Comment: A root service.

Answer (score 0):

You could create global state using ngrx, or a service which has to be available in entire application. In case you have modules, core module would be the best place for it.

Check out documentation for both, so you'll be able to see which one is the best fit for needs of your application.

- [ngrx](https://v9.ngrx.io/guide/store)
- [statefull service](https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services)